Thingspeak notification
I need help with the code, I need this code to work so that when 1 arrives on the thingspeak server, it sends a notification to the application and changes the image from empty_box_background to full_box_background, thank you in advance
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/Cb8j09Yr.png)
